# javascript autocomplete with mouse

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am returning a list of drug names from a database using JavaScript. The autocomplete works and I can select an item with the keyboard by pressing enter but when I click on an item from the drop down list with the mouse nothing gets inputed, and only the part of the string I was typing initially remains.

```
$("#product").typeahead({
    source: function(drug_result, result){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'autocomplete.php',
            method : 'POST',
            data : {drug_result:drug_result},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
            result($.map(data,function(item){
                return item;
        }));
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Comment: looks like your javascript code is incomplete, please paste your full code and the javascript error you are recieving from the console (if there's one)

Comment: This might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735595/bootstrap-typeahead-click-event